# Screenshot the viewport - How do I adjust the quality of the OpenGL render?

Tags: 3d-view, opengl

I just need a simple screenshot of the viewport, the the "render" is all fuzzy. How do I adjust the samples for this kind of render?
[image: screenshot of Blender]

it's all blurry here

[image: Screenshot of blurry render]

Comment: You can change the render image size in the render panel (same as for BI or Cycles rendering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merely illustrating the comment from @Lemon: "You can change the render image size in the render panel".
[image]

Comment: Re: what to do when someone wrote an answer as comment, read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments and https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/why-are-simple-questions-so-often-answered-in-comments

Comment: Aha got it @cegaton! That said... I wasn't sure myself that the answer was so simple, had to try it myself so might as well post the gif! And btw this irrelevant comment will auto delete itself within 24h.